# Convolution matrix sharpen filter

Tags: objective-c, convolution, imagefilter

i trying to implement sharpen convolution matrix filter for image.For this i create matrix 3x3. Maybe i did something wrong with formula?Also i tried other sharpen matrix but it didnt help. Color value could be larger then 255 or smaller then zero so i decide to give some limits on this(0 255).Is it correct solution?

```
static const int filterSmallMatrixSize = 3;
static const int sharpMatrix[3][3] = {{-1, -1, -1},{-1, 9, -1},{-1, -1, -1}};
```

some define

```
#define Mask8(x) ( (x) & 0xFF )
#define R(x) ( Mask8(x) )
#define G(x) ( Mask8(x >> 8 ) )
#define B(x) ( Mask8(x >> 16) )
#define A(x) ( Mask8(x >> 24) )
#define RGBAMake(r, g, b, a) ( Mask8(r) | Mask8(g) << 8 | Mask8(b) << 16 | Mask8(a) << 24 )
```

and algorithm

```
- (UIImage *)processSharpFilterUsingPixels:(UIImage *)inputImage
{
    UInt32 *inputPixels;
    CGImageRef inputCGImage = [inputImage CGImage];
    NSUInteger inputWidth = CGImageGetWidth(inputCGImage);
    NSUInteger inputHeight = CGImageGetHeight(inputCGImage);
    CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
    NSUInteger bytesPerPixel = 4;
    NSUInteger bitsPerComponent = 8;
    NSUInteger inputBytesPerRow = bytesPerPixel * inputWidth;
    inputPixels = (UInt32 *)calloc(inputHeight * inputWidth, sizeof(UInt32));
    CGContextRef context = CGBitmapContextCreate(inputPixels, inputWidth, inputHeight,
                                                 bitsPerComponent, inputBytesPerRow, colorSpace,
                                                 kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast | kCGBitmapByteOrder32Big);
    CGContextDrawImage(context, CGRectMake(0, 0, inputWidth, inputHeight), inputCGImage);

    for (NSUInteger j = 1; j < inputHeight - 1; j++)
    {
        for (NSUInteger i = 1; i < inputWidth - 1; i++)
        {
            Float32 newRedColor = 0;
            Float32 newGreenColor = 0;
            Float32 newBlueColor = 0;
            Float32 newA = 0;

            for (int filterMatrixI = 0 ; filterMatrixI < filterSmallMatrixSize ; filterMatrixI ++)
            {
                for (int filterMatrixJ = 0; filterMatrixJ < filterSmallMatrixSize; filterMatrixJ ++)
                {
                    UInt32 * currentPixel = inputPixels + ((j + filterMatrixJ - 1) * inputWidth) + i + filterMatrixI - 1;
                    int color = *currentPixel;
                    newRedColor += (R(color) * sharpMatrix[filterMatrixI][filterMatrixJ]);
                    newGreenColor += (G(color) * sharpMatrix[filterMatrixI][filterMatrixJ]);
                    newBlueColor += (B(color)* sharpMatrix[filterMatrixI][filterMatrixJ]);
                     newA += (A(color) * sharpMatrix[filterMatrixI][filterMatrixJ]);
                }
            }
            int r = MAX( MIN((int)newRedColor,255), 0);
            int g = MAX( MIN((int)newGreenColor,255), 0);
            int b = MAX( MIN((int)newBlueColor,255), 0);
            int a = MAX( MIN((int)newA,255), 0);
            UInt32 *currentMainImagePixel = inputPixels + (j * inputWidth) + i;
            *currentMainImagePixel = RGBAMake(r,g,b,a);
        }
    }

    CGImageRef newCGImage = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(context);
    UIImage * processedImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:newCGImage];

    CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);
    CGContextRelease(context);
    free(inputPixels);

    return processedImage;
}
```

As result i have this[image: this]

Comment: "Maybe i did something wrong with formula?" - Not sure. Did you not intend this effect? I think it looks quite - interesting. Anyway, don't spam language tags!

Comment: Don't just clip the color values to your bounds and rather scale them. With the given matrix you can get values in a range from -2040 to 2295. Knowing this and the fact that all color values can be between 0 and 255 you can use this formular to scale the values and thus preserve the amount of information: `y = (x + 2040) / (2295 + 2040) * (255 - 0) + 0`, with `x` beeing the filtered values and `y` your new color value between 0 and 255. (General formular to convert x from [a, b] to y in [c, d] is `y =  (x - a) / (b-a) * (d-c) + c)`)

Comment: @Olaf It suppose to be "sharpen" effect :( I added this tags because it a little bit c and c++. Sorry about this.

Comment: @muXXmit2X Can you refactored my code and add correct answer?I have been very grateful to you.

Comment: To mee it looks pretty "sharp":-) (Just teasing a bit - sorry, can't help with that, ObJC is not my language) Anyway, ... and a bit of Java, a bit of Python, etc. pp Identical/similar syntax/grammar does not imply identical semantics. They are all different languages. Please keep that in mind.

Comment: I should have sayed that I'm not sure whether this will solve the problem. But it could. Just exchange the `MAX(MIN())` thing with e.g. `(int)(newRedColor + 2040) / (Float32)(2295 + 2040) * (255 - 0) + 0`.k

Comment: @muXXmit2X            int r = (int)(((newRedColor + 2040.0) * 255.0)/4335.0);
i change formula to ,is it correct?

Comment: @muXXmit2X [link](http://cs622116.vk.me/v622116174/36bbf/UFa72FlssHM.jpg) Im desperate

Comment: you can try to scale down the matrix. [here](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/g8m79etv48ske7h/AADfRNp0IiY90tJDxdN2VVjZa?dl=0) are some results i've got with exactly this filter but with matrices like {0.2, 2.6, 0.2}. low resolution image is 460x366, high is 3280x2606

Comment: also, just noticed that you change pixels in place, so new ones are calculated not from original pixels, but from already changed. i'll check it when i get home again

Comment: @AntonOnizhuk will be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider these are pixels in the middle of image:

```
|_|_|_|_|
|_|_|_|_|
|_|_|_|_|
|_|_|_|_|
```

Since you are updating image in place, this is how it looks somewhere in the middle of sharpen cycle:

```
|u|u|u|u|
|u|u|u|u|
|u|c|_|_|
|_|_|_|_|
```

Where `u` stands for updated pixel, `c` for current. So his new color depends on color of surround pixels, half of which are from already sharpened image, half from origin. To fix it we need a copy of original image's pixels:

```
...
CGContextDrawImage(context, CGRectMake(0, 0, inputWidth, inputHeight), inputCGImage);

UInt32 *origPixels = calloc(inputHeight * inputWidth, sizeof(UInt32));
memcpy(origPixels, inputPixels, inputHeight * inputWidth * sizeof(UInt32));

for (NSUInteger j = 1; j < inputHeight - 1; j++) {
...
```

And now we only need to change one line to get our current pixels from original image

```
//changed inputPixels -> origPixels
UInt32 * currentPixel = origPixels + ((j + filterMatrixJ - 1) * inputWidth) + i + filterMatrixI - 1;
```

[Here are some](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/g8m79etv48ske7h/AADfRNp0IiY90tJDxdN2VVjZa?dl=0) examples of how it works compared to not updated filter (link is dropbox, sorry about that). I've tried different matrices, and as for me the best was somewhere around

```
const float sharpMatrix[3][3] = {{-0.3, -0.3, -0.3},{-0.3, 3.4, -0.3},{-0.3, -0.3, -0.3}}
```

Also, I need to notice that this way of keeping original image is not optimal. My fix basically doubles amount of memory consumed. It could be easily done via holding only two lines of pixels, and I'm sure there are even better ways.